# REST API to get currently logged in user's username confluence server

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am using confluence server 7.13.7. I want a REST API to get the currently logged-in user's username so I can use it in other API calls to fetch more details about the user further.

I know of a way by using the snippet:

```
var userFullname = $("#user-menu-link").attr("title");
```

to get the current user's username. But, in my use case; I am in need of a REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example: (GET)

/rest/api/user/current

from official documentation:
https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/rest/7.13.0/#api/user-getCurrent